# Java - SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect

Tags: java, connection, sockets

My Java connections seem to be failing a lot at the moment.

When I run one piece of software with cmd open I get the above exception and sometimes class files don't load for web based Java programs.

Another PC in my house works so that rules out my router (I believe...) but I can't figure out what is wrong. This is hindering me developing in Java and I would appreciate any ideas / help.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Win7 64bit - OEM, I forgot to mention that this used to work and only recently failed.

Comment: Seems that it is not related to Java at all but more my PC. The installer for Java (which downloads the other installer) fails when I have all Java uninstalled which leaves me to deduce that something on my PC is blocking it. Not a clue what though.

Comment: Did you update anything recently, such as windows or java? I would check the windows firewall rules and make sure that nothing is being blocked.

Comment: Don't believe I did. I've uninstalled / reinstalled Java multiple times with 32bit and 64bit versions. I'm pretty sure I have tried turning off the firewall and testing (win7 one) but I'll try again. The only other thing I run on my PC security wise is MSE.

Comment: http://puu.sh/5mfv - turning off MSE, Win7 Firewall and Router Firewall did nothing.

Comment: That rules out the usual suspects. At this point I'd go to tcpdump to see what is happening when Java sends out the requests. You can get it for windows here: http://www.microolap.com/products/network/tcpdump/download/ - not sure what port it uses, but you can filter it in wireshark after

Comment: Didn't help, anyone else got any ideas?